Primeface13 openDynamic doesn't work NPE exception
I'm using Primeface13, java8 and tomcat9 and I'm trying to open a new page using openDynamic.
I have my test2.xhtml page under webapp folder and my level1.xhtml page under WEB-INF/tag/level1.xhtm.
In faces-config.xml I have put
<action-listener>org.primefaces.application.DialogActionListener</action-listener>
<navigation-handler>org.primefaces.application.DialogNavigationHandler</navigation-handler>
<view-handler>org.primefaces.application.DialogViewHandler</view-handler>

and, inside taglib.xml
<tag>
    <tag-name>level1</tag-name>
    <source>tag/level1.xhtml</source>
</tag>

My test2.html page is
<p:commandButton id="btnPlusFlash" value="View and pass object via flash" icon="pi pi-home"
action="#{dfRootView.openLevel1WithFlash}" styleClass="ml-2">
    <p:ajax event="dialogReturn" listener="#{dfRootView.onReturnFromLevel1}"/>
</p:commandButton>

and my backing bean contains the method called by action
public void openLevel1() {
        Map<String, Object> options = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        options.put("modal", true);
        PrimeFaces.current().dialog().openDynamic("level1", options, null);
    }

public void openLevel1WithFlash() {
   FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getFlash().put("param1", LocalDateTime.now());
       openLevel1();
    }

Then when I try to call the method openDynamic I receive the following error:
com.sun.faces.context.AjaxExceptionHandlerImpl handlePartialResponseError
GRAVE: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.primefaces.application.DialogNavigationHandler.handleNavigation(DialogNavigationHandler.java:56)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.invokeNavigationHandling(ActionListenerImpl.java:110)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:69)
    at org.primefaces.application.DialogActionListener.processAction(DialogActionListener.java:54)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:222)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:847)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1396)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:58)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:76)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:177)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.executeLifecyle(FacesServlet.java:707)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:451)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:144)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:144)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:481)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:130)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:660)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:346)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:388)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:928)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1791)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1190)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:63)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

I tried to change the string inside openDynamic as /WEB-INF/tag/level1 or /tag/level1 and the result is the same,
next I changed the mapping inside taglib.xml with the same strings above without success.
Does anyone have any idea where I'm going wrong?
------ UPDATE -----
After the advices of BalusC and Melloware I removed the the TAG registration and now it works.
The structure is the following
webapp
|
|-test
    |
    |-test2.xhtml
    |-level1.xhtml

and inside the action of the backing bean

PrimeFaces.current().dialog().openDynamic("level1", options, null);

In this way it works

Why exactly did you register it as a tag file? I'm not seeing that requirement anywhere in the PrimeFaces showcase/documentation: https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/df/basic.xhtml

Agreed with BaslusC you don't open a Tag you open an XHTML page with OpenDynamic.  Follow the showcase examples.

I would like to use a tag because I want to reuse that component in other parts. Anyway, I removed the TAG registration and, if I put the leve1 page under the folder where I have the "root" page it works. For instance, if I have webapp/test/test2.xhtml and webapp/test/level1.xhtml and in the backing bean I use PrimeFaces.current().dialog().openDynamic("level1", options, null); it works. Thank you for the advices

You can just keep it a tag file but you need to create a facelet which references that tag file and then reference that facelet instead as dynamic dialog. E.g. <ui:composition ...><my:level1></ui:composition>.
